# How to find a adress from GPS coordinates via API OpenStreetMap?

Tags: openstreetmap

How to find a adress from GPS coordinates via API OpenStreetMap?

I can use any language (javascript, java, ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Reverse geocoding

The task you're looking for is called *reverse geocoding* - reverse to ordinary geocoding, which returns the coordinates of an address.

Some ways to do that include the python `geocoder` module ( https://geocoder.readthedocs.io/api.html#reverse-geocoding ) or the OpenStreetMap Nominatim API https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim#Reverse_Geocoding

Comment: Also see other [OSM-based Geocoders](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Search_engines) such as Photon.